# table value sorting in lua

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I got an table like this:

```
tbl = {
    ['etc1'] = 1337,
    ['etc2'] = 14477,
    ['etc3'] = 1336,
    ['etc4'] = 1335
}
```

And now I need to sort this table to get output from highes to lowest value:

```
tbl = {
    ['etc2'] = 14477,
    ['etc1'] = 1337,
    ['etc3'] = 1336,
    ['etc4'] = 1335
}
```

Already tried lots of functions like table.sort or others from the official manual, but nothing helped. So hope you'll help me out guys!

Regards.

Comment: @mods, sorry, I submitted the flag too soon, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726130/lua-desc-sorting-table-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua tables do not have ordering other than by their keys.  You will need to structure your data more like this:

```
tbl = {
    [1] = { ['etc2'] = 14477 },
    [2] = { ['etc1'] = 1337 },
    [3] = { ['etc3'] = 1336 },
    [4] = { ['etc4'] = 1335 }
}
```

or this:

```
tbl = {
    [1] = { 'etc2', 14477 },
    [2] = { 'etc1', 1337 },
    [3] = { 'etc3', 1336 },
    [4] = { 'etc4', 1335 }
}
```

or this, if you want to use it in conjunction with the original table:

```
tbl_keys = {
    [1] = 'etc2',
    [2] = 'etc1',
    [3] = 'etc3',
    [4] = 'etc4'
}
```

Note that I was very explicit and wrote all the numeric indices.  You can of course omit them, so the last solution would be:

```
tbl_keys = {
    'etc2',
    'etc1',
    'etc3',
    'etc4'
}
```

Maybe this means you should write a function which turns the original data into this new form, or maybe you can get it done earlier on, before the table is made in the first place.

Comment: Well.

I am creating my table in this way:

    dmg = {}
    if not dmg[attacker] then
        dmg[attacker] = value
    else
        dmg[attacker] = dmg[attacker] + value
    end

So, how can I change it so output can look's like one of your example? 

fe. :

    tbl = {
        [1] = { ['etc2'] = 14477 },
        [2] = { ['etc1'] = 1337 },
        [3] = { ['etc3'] = 1336 },
        [4] = { ['etc4'] = 1335 }
    }

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you try it and post a new question if you get stuck?

Comment: I see you posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726130/lua-desc-sorting-table-problem