# sorting a table in descending order in Lua

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I can not get it work:

```
tbl = {
    [1] = { ['etc2'] = 14477 },
    [2] = { ['etc1'] = 1337 },
    [3] = { ['etc3'] = 1336 },
    [4] = { ['etc4'] = 1335 }
}

for i = 1, #tbl do
    table.sort(tbl, function(a, b) return a[i] > b[i] end)
    print(tbl[i] .. '==' .. #tbl)
end
```

Getting this error: attempt to compare two nil values

This is a follow-on to [table value sorting in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725707/lua-desc-table-value-sorting/6725769#comment-7966877)

Comment: I don't think you want to sort your table inside the loop. Also, how exactly are you trying to sort it? `a[i]` is nil because `a` is a table with string indexes.

Comment: Welcome to SO Lucas.  When you need to clarify your question, use the edit button beneath you post rather than opening new questions.  I'll flag the other two as duplicates of this one since I believe this Q&A best handles the problem.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038418/associatively-sorting-a-table-by-value-in-lua

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
tbl = {
    { 'etc3', 1336 },
    { 'etc2', 14477 },
    { 'etc4', 1335 },
    { 'etc1', 1337 },
}

table.sort(tbl, function(a, b) return a[2] > b[2] end)

for k,v in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(v[1], ' == ', v[2])
end
```

Organizing the data that way made it easier to sort, and note that I only call `table.sort` once, not once per element of the table.  And I sort based on the second value in the subtables, which I think is what you wanted.