# How does one reverse the items in a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there something that would do the same thing as table.sort, but backwards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting a table in descending order in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726130/sorting-a-table-in-descending-order-in-lua)

Comment: Have you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726130/sorting-a-table-in-descending-order-in-lua)?

Comment: Do you want to _"sort a table in reverse order"_ or _"just reverse the items in a table"_? Those are completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

The table.sort function allows you to define a sorting function as the second argument. It returns a boolean and specifies the order on which the table must be ordered:

```
local atable = {1,2,3}
table.sort(atable, function(a,b) return a > b end)
for _, v in pairs(atable) do
    print(v)
end
--[[This prints:
3
2
1
]]
```

Of course, this doesn't limit itself to "lists" but you can use them on other table types as well:

```
local cityInfo = {
{name = "Vancouver", population = 321, location = "Canada"},
{name = "Paris", population = 123, location = "France"},
{name = "London", population = 1000, location = "United Kingdom"},
}
table.sort(cityInfo, function(a,b) return a.population > b.population end) -- Here the items are ordered in descencing order based on the population field
for _, v in pairs(cityInfo) do
    print(v.population)
end
--[[This prints:
1000
321
123
]]
```

Comment: "Of course, this doesn't limit itself to "lists" but you can use them on other table types as well" - this is plain wrong. `table.sort` **is literally limited to the list part of the table**. Your first table is a "list" of primitive values (numbers) whereas your second table is a "list" of tables. Both are lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a table in reverse order:

```lua
table.sort(your_table, function(x, y) return x > y end)
```

If you want to reverse a table:

```lua
local function reverse(tab)
    for i = 1, #tab//2, 1 do
        tab[i], tab[#tab-i+1] = tab[#tab-i+1], tab[i]
    end
    return tab
end
```

Comment: I get: `unexpected symbol near '/'`

Comment: @MaartenWolzak, the integer divide operator was added in Lua 5.3. The alternative to `x//2` would be `x>>1` or `math.floor(x/2)`.